# How do I know which Windowing system, display server and a window manager I am running on GNU/Linux?

Tags: command, window-manager, display-server

I really liked following diagram from Wikipedia which shows how different graphical components are connected to each other.:

> [image: diagram]

As per my understanding, here 1) "graphical interface" is closely related to what we know as "Desktop Environment" as KDE, GNOME etc. are given examples. 2) X11 etc. are "windowing systems" 3) Xorg, Mutter etc. are listed as display servers and 4) Compiz etc. are window managers

A normal users or those who are new to GNU/Linux would probably know only about Desktop Environment, not about rest of components. I want to know which of each components are running on my system.

So, How do I know which Windowing system, which display server and which display server I am using on my GNU/Linux system? (*preferably through command line*)

Comment: Note: If you find the question can be closed as duplicate of combination of couple of questions, add those links while closing

Comment: Found an answer and self-closed as duplicate. Btw, I have [learned it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55020743#55020743)